# Is there an API convert long/lat to city,country rather than Google API

Tags: api, location, latitude-longitude, city, geonames

Is there an API convert long/lat to city,country rather than Google API?

I found that geonames does not give the city.

Thanks,
Ling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, outside the US the geonames API call 'extendedFindNearby' does in fact give city/country hierachy rather than just the address information.
EG:
http://ws.geonames.org/extendedFindNearby?lat=-34.9663955375277&lng=150.719617020043